# Open TIFF image in Python

Tags: python, raster, geotiff-tiff, jupyter-notebook

I'm working with jupyter and I have been trying to open TIFF images that I have download from GEE. I have trying to open the images in Jupyter environment.

This is my code:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy 

img = Image.open("NDVI.tif")
```

but I get the following error message:

> OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call
>   last)  in 
>   ----> 1 img = Image.open("NDVI.tif")
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in open(fp, mode)    2820
>   for message in accept_warnings:    2821         warnings.warn(message)
>   -> 2822     raise IOError("cannot identify image file %r" % (filename if filename else fp))    2823     2824
>
> OSError: cannot identify image file 'NDVI.tif'

I have tried to change the raster nae to end with TIFF and tiff but didn't help.
How can I solve this?

EDIT: This is where my jupyter notebook is and where the tif are:
[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do? If you need to process the images mathematically, it's better to use rasterio, it will read it into a numpy matrix and then you'd process it.

Otherwise, I'm not sure, but probably the Tiff has some special data type (intX, for instance).

Comment: @culebrón i'm trying to create scattter plot between two bands ,each band in different image

Comment: then you definitely need to use `rasterio`. https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Comment: I can open whatever image with Image method from PIL. So, you don't have  'NDVI.tif' in your work directory, Anaconda cannot interpret adequately your path or your image is corrupted.

Comment: oh, @xunilk is right. My bad.

Comment: @xunilk  , I add on the original post image- I think they are on the correct directory, isn't it?